# Max count of ID in table

Tags: sql

I have a table (orders) in my SQL db and want to know which article (articleID) was sold most. I'm currently using the the following statement:

```
SELECT articleID FROM orders 
GROUP BY articleID 
ORDER BY COUNT(articleID) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It works but I was wondering if there is any better solution for that. Couldn't find anything similar in previous posts - if you do, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: what have you reearched, understand your probably learning but this is covered easily by a google search
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp

Comment: @Tik does the link you posted have anything to do with the question?

Comment: i don't know any/see a better alternative for your query!  (January, 2019) ..but "question title" is somewhat "off" / confusing:)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: As long as `article_id` is indexed, and since it's presumably a foreign key it should be, this is fine.

Comment: If there is one article with maximum number of sales your query will return that article.
If there are more than one article with the same maximum number of sales your query will return only one of them, the first in order by. 
In my answer, I wrote the query which will return all articles with maximum number of sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `articleid` is indexed, presumably it's a foreign key so it should already be, your query is fine. An `explain analyze` shows what's going on. You didn't mention which database you're using, so this is Postgres.

```
test=> select count(*) from orders;
  count  
---------
3003116

test=> select count(distinct articleid) from orders;
  count  
---------
 1999922

test=> explain analyze SELECT articleID FROM orders 
GROUP BY articleID 
ORDER BY COUNT(articleID) DESC LIMIT 1;
                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=149534.48..149534.48 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=1446.766..1446.767 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=149534.48..156236.51 rows=2680814 width=12) (actual time=1446.765..1446.765 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(articleid)) DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..136130.41 rows=2680814 width=12) (actual time=3.772..1245.538 rows=1999922 loops=1)
               Group Key: articleid
               ->  Index Only Scan using orders_article_id on orders  (cost=0.43..94306.81 rows=3003092 width=4) (actual time=1.307..648.542 rows=3003116 loops=1)
                     Heap Fetches: 3003116
 Planning time: 4.692 ms
 Execution time: 1446.809 ms
```

Most of the cost is in scanning the index and aggregating the result. The `order by` is very cheap.

The cost increases linearly with your number of orders. Double the orders, double the cost. If this is not acceptable you can instead make a separate table for order statistics and update it either periodically or with triggers.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, I rid off ORDER BY, it's slow operation.

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C1, articleID FROM orders
GROUP BY articleID)
SELECT articleID FROM T
WHERE C1 = (SELECT MAX(C1) FROM T)
```

Comment: This is about 50% more expensive. Most of the cost of the original query is scanning the index, performing the count, and aggregating it for the group by. The sort is inconsequential. This does the same thing, but instead of a cheap sort it does an extra expensive aggregate. [Here's the explains](https://gist.github.com/schwern/146345bcc53beacb2d9eecff28fef3f6).

Comment: @Schwern, I didn't go in such deep analysis of this query as you did.
Can you explain me when you said 'instead of a cheap sort it does an extra expensive aggregate'
I find this on your explanation for sort and aggregation operation.            
 - Sort (cost=49033.06..51284.44 rows=900554 width=12) (actual time=539.010..539.010 rows=1 loops=1)              
 - Aggregate (cost=20262.47..20262.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=807.957..807.957 rows=1 loops=1)

If we have two articleID with same number sold, this query will resolve that issues.

Comment: I was mistaken. The `order by` is consequential, removing it makes the original query return instantly. But `max` also has to sort the counts. Your query is doing basically the same operations as the original, but less efficiently.